# android studio зависает. Комп сильный

Tags: android-studio, mac

Комп Mac pro 15, i7, 16gb ram, 512SSD
Давно работаю с Android Studio, но на другом компе, почти на половину меньшей мощности этого компа. На нем все отлично работает. А на маке че-то медленно очень.
Например редактирую код xml и даже если прокручивать страницу, то зависает на секунду 1-2. В системе смотрю, нагрузка около 15-30 процентов. Причем другие программы отлично работают. Как можно решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел проблему. Надо было увеличить выделенный рам для этой программы. Для этого надо переходить на:

> Help -> Edit custom VM options

и увеличить там значения. В моем случае:

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx7000m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2000m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=2000m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```